# communication between windows client and linux server?

Tags: c, linux, windows, networking, udp

I am performing communication between client(windows) and server(linux RT) in c. I have written a client code for windows operating system (one laptop) and server code for linux operating system (another laptop). I am connecting the both laptop via ethernet cable and configured them on the same subnet.

SERVER.c : Linux

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFLEN 512
#define PORT 9930

void err(char *str)
{
    perror(str);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr, cli_addr;
    int sockfd, i;
    socklen_t slen=sizeof(cli_addr);
    char buf[BUFLEN];

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
      err("socket");
    else
      printf("Server : Socket() successful\n");

    bzero(&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr* ) &my_addr, sizeof(my_addr))==-1)
      err("bind");
    else
      printf("Server : bind() successful\n");

    while(1)
    {
        if (recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, 

&slen)==-1)
            err("recvfrom()");
        printf("Received packet from %s:%d\nData: %s\n\n",
               inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port), buf);
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

CLIENT.c - windows

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <io.h> 
#define BUFLEN 512
#define PORT 9930

void err(char *str)
{
    perror(str);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr, cli_addr;
    int sockfd, i;
    socklen_t slen=sizeof(cli_addr);
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;

     printf("Initializing Winsock\n");
     wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD (1, 1);
     if (WSAStartup (wVersionRequested, &wsaData) != 0){
      printf("Winsock initialised failed \n");
     } else {
       printf("Initialised\n");


if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1)
    err("socket");

bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
if (inet_aton(argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)==0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed\n");
    exit(1);
}


     while(1)
{
    printf("\nEnter data to send(Type exit and press enter to exit) : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",buf);
    getchar();
    if(strcmp(buf,"exit") == 0)
      exit(0);

    if (sendto(sockfd, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, slen)==-1)
        err("sendto()");
}

close(sockfd);
return 0;
```

}

My question :

- Is it possible to perform communication like this ??
- Do I want to take specific measures for doing this ??

Please give ideas regarding this ?

Comment: Sure this works. Or do you think one needs to know what operating system the server runs on to look at a specific web page?

Comment: @PMF the OPs question is about _directly_ connecting two laptops via a cable. No network involved.

Comment: do I want to cross compile ??

Comment: Since you have said you've written code, can you please include it in here formatted and _neat_

Comment: @arkascha : how is it possible by just connecting a cable ? :P

Comment: No, you do _not_ want to "cross compile", this has nothing to do with compiling. We are talking about networking here, are we not? For the "how": see my answer.

Comment: Also make sure that the firewalls, if any, allow the communication. For experimenting purpose, it would be good to temporarily disable firewall on both the systems.

Comment: you can see my above code. It is showing error in client side as : undefined reference to winsock, undefined reference to socket@2, undefined reference to bzero, undefined reference to htons@4

Comment: For the socket error add ws2_32.lib to your link.  Can't see how your code can possibly work - both sides are receiving, nobody is sending.  Shouldn't it be one sending, one receiving?

Comment: Also, on the windows side, sockfd is of type SOCKET which is not an int.  You can't just close it - use closesocket followed by WSACleanup.

Comment: sorry. now i changed my code. I added ws2_32.lib in client side.

Comment: could some one tell me how to send a response back to the client ?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect two systems directly (via ethernet cable), but typically you must use a special cable for that: it is called a "crossover cable". Otherwise no connection is possible.

Newer network controllers implement a detection for this kind of setup, so it might be possible to use a standard cable for this setup, but this depends on the network controllers build into the two systems. You will have to try or consult the documentation.

Also it migh be that you have to select some special configuration on the MS-Windows side (inside the network adapter configuration) for this to work. I experienced communication problems with the standard setup a few times. You can consult google for those settings.

Comment: While this is theoretically true, AFAIK, the ethernet controllers these days, usually detect in hardware, if a standard cable is used instead of cross-cable & accordingly handle it in hardware, so that both kind of cables work. However, using cross-cable is the correct way.

Comment: This is actually true, thanks for mentioning that. So it depends on the network controllers build into the laptops if a standard cable can be used or a crossover cable is required. I adapted the answer accordingly.

Comment: you can see my above code. It is showing error in client side as :     undefined reference to winsock, undefined reference to socket@2, undefined reference to bzero, undefined reference to htons@4

Comment: Sorry, nothing I can say about these details, since I have next to no experience in MS-Windows programming. I am a convinced Linux user ;-)