# is it possible to send a respose from udp server to client ?

Tags: c, linux, windows, udp, embedded-linux

I posted my code here: [communication between windows client and linux server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372131/communication-between-windows-client-and-linux-server?noredirect=1#comment34008685_22372131)

I am performing communication between client and server.I know that udp is a connectionless program nothing but it wont send any response back to the client. If i want to send a response back to the client then what should i do ??
I solved all my errors in the above link but I got a doubt w.r.t sending a response back to the client. so i am re posting here.

Comment: Post cards and letters are also connectionless. Have you ever responded to someone who wrote you a letter?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I wrote when I start learning socket programming, hope it helps:

**server**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    int socket_fd;
    int ret;
    char buf[255];
    int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(socket_fd < 0)
    {
        printf("socket error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(5900);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    ret = bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    if(ret)
    {
        printf("error while binding\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ret = recvfrom(socket_fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);

    if(ret < 0)
    {
        printf("reciving error\n");
    }

    printf("recving data from %s: %s\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr), buf);

    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "server:");
    ret = sendto(socket_fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(client));

    if(ret < 0)
    {
        printf("send error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    close(socket_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

**client**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socket_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    int ret;
    char buf[255] = "send to server";
    int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(socket_fd < 0)
    {
        printf("socket error\n");  
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(5900);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    ret = sendto(socket_fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));

    if(ret < 0)
    {
        printf("sendto error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ret = recvfrom(socket_fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server, &len); 
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        printf("error recv from\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("recving from server:%s: %s\n", inet_ntoa(server.sin_addr), buf);

    close(socket_fd);
}
```

**Read the code above and you will find the answer to your question**